# Batch cannot find file specific, but printed filepath is correct?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've written a really basic batch script (which worked originally) to just copy a file from a subdirectory to the root (the root being where the command was run), backing up the original file if needed. Below is my script with substitutions. The file copied from `%CD%\folder\` has the same filename as `%FILE%`

```
set /p backup=Do you want to backup your current file? (Yes or No): 
set file=filename.cmd

if %BACKUP% == Yes (
    if exist "%FILE%-backup" (
        del "%FILE%-backup"
    )
    rename "%FILE%" "%FILE%-backup"
) else (
    del "%FILE%"
)

xcopy "%CD%\folder\%FILE%" "%CD%"
```

The idea being that the file is renamed to `filename.cmd-backup` if the user selects to back up the file.

However, at the end of the if statement I'm getting an error when running it through CMD (I've aligned it so it's easier to read, this is my exact CMD output):

```
if Yes == Yes ( 
    if exist "filename.cmd-backup" ( 
        del "filename.cmd-backup"
    )
    rename "filename.cmd" "filename.cmd-backup"
) else (
    del "C:\path\to\file\filename.cmd"
)
The system can not find the file specified.
```

Am I missing something stupid?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything was fine syntactically. The file I wanted to rename was hidden and I didn't realise.

So two options, either make the file unhidden or change to the following:

```
set /p backup=Do you want to backup your current file? (Yes or No): 
set file=filename.cmd

if %BACKUP% == Yes (
    if exist "%FILE%-backup" (
        del "%FILE%-backup"
    )
    attrib -H "%FILE%"
    rename "%FILE%" "%FILE%-backup"
) else (
    attrib -H "%FILE%"
    del "%FILE%"
)

xcopy "%CD%\folder\%FILE%" "%CD%"
```

Comment: A (very) minor note: since you are doing `attrib -H "%FILE%"` regardless of the user input, you might as well do it before the `if` statement to avoid repeating the command in the script. Other than that – well, this must have been a nasty bug to find, so congrats on working it out!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that when the script gets down to `xcopy`, the filename in `%file%` no longer exists.

If you do backup, then it is renamed to `filename.cmd-backup`, and if you don't then it is deleted.

Either way it goes, the file `filename.cmd` no longer exists.

Comment: A file of the same filename exists in the %CD%\folder directory too